# Reading hexadecimals from a text file

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I am new to C and would like to ask the following question which I have struggled for a period of time. :( Please help!

I want to read a plaintext file, passout.txt which contains a string of hexadecimal like:

```
A1B2C3D4E5403E9D501B223AD45523D6
```

and put them into an array like :

```
{A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, 40, 3E, 9D, 50, 1B, 22, 3A, D4, 55, 23, D6}
```

However, my current output is only :

```
{D4, 55, 23, D6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Only the last four hexidecimals can be retrieved only! I really don't know what mistakes I have made and I couldn't find any related solution from the web! Therefore, would anybody please help?

Here's my code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16

void main()
{
    FILE *ifp;
    int i, rv;
    unsigned char in[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};

    ifp = fopen("passout.txt", "r");

    // loop and read the input file
    for(i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        rv = fscanf(ifp, "%X", &in[i]);
        if(rv != 1)
            i = AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    printf("Print result: \n");
    for(i=0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%X ",*(in+i));
    printf("\n");   

    fclose(ifp);
}
```

Comment: You need to copy pairs of hex digits to a buffer and convert each pair to a byte. This allows to convert any length of hex string.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind giving me an exmaple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rv = fscanf(ifp, "%X", &in[i]);
```

change to

```
rv = fscanf(ifp, "%2hhX", &in[i]);
```

---

for before C99

```
unsigned X;
rv = fscanf(ifp, "%2X", &X);
if(rv != 1)
    break;
in[i] = (unsigned char)X;
```

Comment: Explanation would be nice. 2hhX is very unusual.

Comment: `hhX` for `unsigned char` since `C99`. `2` is max field size.

Comment: It is what it is written in reference perhaps. They use the function without reading such a description.  I cannot be well understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach fails since the output format of sscanf is *one* number.

Your approach fails since the output format of sscanf is *one* number.You need to copy pairs of hex digits to a buffer and convert each pair to a byte. This allows to convert any length of hex string.